# Android Bluetooth Low Energy stack and the 24-bit CRC computation

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, crc

Vol 6, Part B, section 2.1 (page 2562) of [Bluetooth Core Specification version 5.0](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=421043&_ga=2.10887604.1400730147.1535461476-1667346193.1514985300)  defines the Link Layer packet format for the Bluetooth Low Energy Uncoded PHYs. In this packet format, a 24-bit CRC is included and is used to detect errors in digital data.

In BlueZ, the open-source official Linux Bluetooth protocol stack, this CRC is computed using the crc24_calculate() function (see [ll.c](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez/blob/bc704506e69ae30b0770aac32504e89cf2dc9ddf/monitor/ll.c)).

Regarding this example, I'm wondering where I can find the computation of this 24-bit CRC in the [Bluetooth Android open-source code](https://android.googlesource.com/) ?

Indeed, from what I've previously read on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167451/how-can-get-crc-from-android-ble-scan-result),

> The Bluetooth controller will discard packets where the CRC doesn't
>   match the packet contents. The Bluetooth controller does not forward the CRC to the main CPU so you you can't get it.

Actually, if it is the case, how can I be sure that only packets with a verified 24-bit CRC are handled in the Bluetooth Android host stack ?

Thanks in advance for your help :).

Comment: Unless you have some form of packet sniffer to get all of the packet, you may not be able to get the CRC. Also, there are two main ways to verify a CRC, one is to generate the CRC based on message data and compare the CRC bytes, the other is to generate the CRC on the message and appended CRC and check for the "re-encoded" CRC == 0 (if the CRC is post complemented, a good "re-encoded" CRC will be some fixed non-zero value, but most implementations of CRC don't do this).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, Android gives no access to the 24-bit CRC of the BLE packets. As a consequence, I cannot use the two ways that you described to verify a CRC, right ? I have the intuition that Android processes BLE packets at lower level (Link or PHY layers) and only returns packets with a correct CRC in the host. What I wanted is just to be sure that it is the case and, as far as I know, I have not found an official Android documentation or a source code where it is explicitly written...